# What kind of movie would you all like to watch? ---CORRECT?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, modal-verbs, spoken-english

I'm not sure about the following sentence-constructions:

> What kind of movie **would you all** like to watch?
>
> What kind of movie **you all would** like to watch?

---

Which one is correct (and idiomatic)?

Comment: What kind of movie would all of you like to watch? - is what I would have said.

Comment: Out of the two, I would go for the former.